# How to pass an enum to Html.RadioButtonFor to get a list of radio buttons in MVC 2 RC 2, C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, enums, radio-button

I'm trying to render a radio button list in MVC 2 RC 2 (C#) using the following line:

```
<%= Html.RadioButtonFor(model => Enum.GetNames(typeof(DataCarry.ProtocolEnum)),
                        null) %>
```

but it's just giving me the following exception at runtime:

> Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

Is this possible and if so, how, please?

Answer (score 6):

You can create a template called "Enum" in /Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Enum.ascx

With the following content:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList(string.Empty, Enum.GetNames(Model.GetType()).ToList().ConvertAll(e => new SelectListItem() { Text = e.ToString(), Value = e , Selected = e.Equals(Model.ToString())}))  %>
```

This just enumerates the enum values.

You can call this with

```
Html.EditorFor(m => m.YourEnumProperty, "Enum" /*The name of the template*/)
```

Comment: Of course you can change it from DropDownList -- the generation of the select list is the main part. :-)

Comment: I don't see an equivalent method on `Html.RadioButtonFor`.  It seems that helper method only takes one value.  Is there an alternative that does what the OP asks?

Comment: -1 `RadioButton` and `RadioButtonFor` don't take `SelectListItem`s.

Answer (score 1):

Try [GetValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx) instead