# Is there a way to display an int property as text in the ui?

Tags: c#, user-interface, asp.net-mvc-3, user-input

I'm not sure if this is possible, or if it is an acceptable/unacceptable practice, but I have an int property (Gender) on my Person object, and I'm wondering if there is a way that I could display text (and radio buttons, assuming those are the best option) for the user to select (i.e. "male" and "female"), rather than displaying it as numbers.  I'm assuming it is possible, but I don't know where to start.  Would it be some customization directly on the property, maybe in the service layer?  I have some customization with "Format" and "Caption" on other properties there.  Here's all I have for Gender:

```
properties.Add(new PropertyData { Property = "Gender", Type = "Int32", Value = data.Gender.ToString() });
```

Or would it be directly in the view?  This is what I have right now - just a text box where you can type an integer.

```
<p class="span1">
    @Html.Label(Model.Person.Properties, "Gender")
    @Html.TextBox(Model.Person.Properties, "Gender")
    @Html.Tip(Model.Person.Properties, "Gender")
</p>
```

Any help is appreciated. :)  Please let me know if I need to supply any additional information or code.

EDIT:
I used the following:

```
<p>
    @Html.Label(Model.Person.Properties, "Gender")
    <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="1" /><span>Male</span>
    <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="2" /><span>Female</span>
</p>
```

Is there a way to keep the button selected when I pull up my Person to edit?  Everything else (i.e. current data for the record) repopulates on the Edit form.   (Should this be a separate question?)

Comment: Do you need to have gender as an integer? A boolean would be better

Comment: OT: on a metaphysical level, the question should be the other way around: How would you display an int, if not in text? (bar charts, sliders, pictogram counts) :)

Comment: @user673289, I'm not sure what the perceived benefit is to having it as an integer.  That was how I was told to create it, but I can see your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this post and see if it helps: [How to pass an enum to Html.RadioButtonFor to get a list of radio buttons in MVC 2 RC 2, C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222743/how-to-pass-an-enum-to-html-radiobuttonfor-to-get-a-list-of-radio-buttons-in-mvc)

In short

1. Create a gender enum
2. Use a method to read the gender name
   from the enum
3. Set the value of the radio button to
   the value of the enum

Comment: Thank you for your input.  This is what I've created, going from the first answer, from @Tejs:

    <p>
        @Html.Label(Model.Person.Properties, "Gender")
        <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="1" /><span>Male</span>
        <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="2" /><span>Female</span>
    </p>

Do you see a benefit to doing it with the gender enum?  To me, it seems more complex than necessary for only two options... but I am still a newbie, so maybe I'm missing something else.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to tag you in my comment above.  I'm not sure if you'll see it otherwise.  (I deleted this, thinking I could edit my original comment, but it looks like you can only edit your most recent?  :/  Sorry about that.)

Comment: @White Island The benefit of the enum is that your code is more readable. What is easier to understand, Gender = 1 or Gender = Female? Someone unfamiliar with your code will not have any idea what Gender = 1 means.

Comment: I did end up using an enum and just a drop-down list, rather than a radio button.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In MVC, you have complete control over the HTML you render. So you have a couple of options here. You can manually render the HTML as you want it:

```
<input type="radio" name="SomeName" value="1"><span>Male</span>
<!-- Etc for each item !-->
```

Or, you can use one of the other HtmlHelpers to do that:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Person.Properties, "Male")
@Html.RadioButtonListFor (Custom)
```

There is more information [here](http://glenmcg.blogspot.com/2010/04/strongly-typed-radiobuttonlist-for.html) on how you can implement your own radio button list in MVC3.

Comment: thank you for your quick response and the clear instructions.  I ended up using an enum and a drop-down list, rather than a radio button.